# How to promote container in kubernetes to another namespace(environment/DTAP)?

Tags: kubernetes, release-management

I would like to deploy a container to one specific namespace, let's call it `dev` and easily promote it to `test`-->`acc`-->`prod` namespace. 
Reason we use `dev`-->`test`-->`acc`-->`prod` in cluster ` is mainly testing and integration with external parties.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily deploy container to any namespace. Actually, you should set the namespace to which you are going to deploy your container, but you can not move your container from one namespace to another, because after spawn the container will be in one namespace until it dies. The best way to achieve your goal is to use the image version. You can start to deploy the image version 1.0.1 to namespace `dev`,  work on it, and then use this image for container in `test`  namespace.  As a result, you will have the same container but in the new namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the image currently deployed in your dev namespace (assuming your current namespace is dev):

```
kubectl describe pods
```

And look at the Image field. Copy the image name with its version and update the image in test:

```
kubectl set image deployment/<your-deployment> <your-image-name>=<paste-here-image-with-version> --namespace=<your-test-namespace>
```